# Accessing Multiple camera javascript getusermedia

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webcam, getusermedia

guys i have two cameras that is
-the web camera
-the laptop camera

i want to stream those camera in a website
i already have some reference
here is some code that is working on jsfiddle
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jayzlov/tVpvb/)

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap" class="sexyButton">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script>

    // Put event listeners into place
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            video = document.getElementById("video"),
            videoObj = { "video": true },
            errBack = function(error) {
                console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
            };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        }

        // Trigger photo take
        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        });
    }, false);

</script>
```

that example can only connects and select 1 camera
i want to select and view two of my camera, any suggestion or solution guys?
you can also give me the JS fiddle

Comment: You can refer to this question - [Enable rear camera with HTML5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625007/enable-rear-camera-with-html5)

Answer (score 11):

You can create two different streams, one for each camera, and show them simultaneously in two `<video>` tags.

The list of available devices is available using [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices). After filtering the resulting list for only `videoinput`s, you have access to the `deviceId`s without needing permission from the user.

With [`getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) you can then request a stream from the camera with id `camera1Id` using

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    deviceId: { exact: camera1Id }
  }
});
```

The resulting `stream` can be fed into a `<video>` (referenced here by `vid`) by calling `vid.srcObject = stream`.

I have done this for two streams from two webcams simultaneously.

Comment: Not working with Chrome on Android front and back camera

Comment: @astronought. Sure that the device can actually do that natively?

Comment: @J0hj0h navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() can not detect both webcam in my laptop. It only detects [audioinput, videoinput, audiooutput]. I have two videoinput but it does not have access to another. I use latest version of chrome in windows.

Comment: enumerateDevices() is not giving device id. It may give once we call getUserMedia() on that device specifically. But to call this function, we need exact Id. So its kind circular dependency... any solution please suggest...

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access two cameras simultaneously. The API would indicate otherwise, but something underlying seems to prevent it from working as expected. You can verify this by opening https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/ or http://googlechrome.github.io/webrtc/samples/web/content/getusermedia-source/ in two completely seperate windows, despite being able to select two streams only one is active at once - if you pick the same one in both windows, then it shows in both places.
The only workaround I was able to do was to flip-flop between the two streams, then draw the video to a canvas. Doing this I was able to do captures at around 1 fps, unfortunately the camera resets between frames, on one of my cameras I had to put in a delay to allow the auto white balance to kick in to get a decent image.

```
function webcam() {
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
}

if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    return alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var audioSource;
var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 2);
var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight/2);
//canvas.width = cw;
//canvas.height = ch;

//off dom video player
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.autoplay="autoplay";
video.addEventListener('playing', function(){
    //delay for settling...
    setTimeout(draw,1000,this,context,(currentSource*canvas.clientWidth/2),cw,ch);
},false);

function captureVideo() {
    console.log("Capturing " + currentSource,videosources[currentSource]);
    var mediaOptions = {
        audio: {
            optional: [{sourceId: audioSource}]
        },
        video: {
            optional: [
                {sourceId: videosources[currentSource].id}
            ]
        }};
    navigator.getUserMedia(mediaOptions, success, errorCallback);
}
var currentSource=0;
var videosources = [];
var lastStream;
function errorCallback(error){
    console.log("navigator.getUserMedia error: ", error);
}
function success(stream) {

    console.log("the stream" + currentSource,stream);
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
    lastStream=stream;
}
function next(){

    if(lastStream){
        lastStream.stop();
    }
    video.src = "";
    if(currentSource < videosources.length-1){
        currentSource+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        currentSource=0;
    }
    captureVideo();
}
function draw(v,c,l,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    console.log("drawing",l)
    c.drawImage(v,l,0,w,h);
    setTimeout(next,500);
}

MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function (sourceInfos) {

    for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (sourceInfo.kind === 'audio') {
            console.log(sourceInfo.id, sourceInfo.label || 'microphone');
            audioSource=sourceInfo.id;

        } else if (sourceInfo.kind === 'video') {
            console.log(sourceInfo.id, sourceInfo.facing, sourceInfo.label || 'camera');
            videosources.push(sourceInfo);

        } else {
            console.log('Some other kind of source: ', sourceInfo);
        }
    }
console.log("sources",videosources)
    next();
});
}
```

Comment: As of 2018, the linked website works and multiple video streams can be shown simultaneously.

Comment: Correction: Video streams can be shown in two tabs or windows simultaneously, as long as they belong to the same browser. If Firefox has opened a stream, then Chrome will fail, and vice versa, but when using the same browser, everything works.