# Record front and back webcams at the same time

Tags: javascript, webcam, getusermedia, video-recording

I have the following code which records with the back camera of the tablet for 5 seconds and downloads the video:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(devices => {
          var deviceId = [];
          devices.forEach(function(device) {
            if ( device.kind == 'videoinput' )
              deviceId.push(device.deviceId);
          });
          // deviceId[0] equals the id of the front camera (resolution: 1280x720)
          // deviceId[1] equals the id of the back camera (resolution: 1920x1080)
          navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { deviceId: { exact: deviceId[1] }, width: 1920, height: 1080 } })
            .then(stream => record(stream, 5000)
              .then(recording => {
                stop(stream);
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recording));
                a.download = "recording.webm";
                a.click();
              })
              .catch(log).then(() => stop(stream)))
            .catch(log);
        })
        .catch(log);

        var record = (stream, ms) => {
          var rec = new MediaRecorder(stream), data = [];
          rec.ondataavailable = e => data.push(e.data);
          rec.start();
          var stopped = new Promise((r, e) => (rec.onstop = r, rec.onerror = e));
          return Promise.all([stopped, wait(ms).then(() => rec.stop())])
            .then(() => data);
        };

        var stop = stream => stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
        var log = err => console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I record both the front and back webcams of the tablet at the same time and download the videos as seperated files.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22787549/7393973) but it's old so I'm not sure if it's possible or not today.

Comment: The question is the same. If the answer were to change, I would think it'd be because newer phone hardware supports it, without requiring any change in how you access it. Have you found a device that claims to support it?

Comment: @jib I don't know if the tablets/phones are capable or not, I just thought that maybe they could record both cameras at the same time.

Comment: That sounds like a hardware question, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow. I.e. the code above should work fine on a desktop computer with multiple cameras attached.