# How to access external cameras?

Tags: javascript, mobile, camera, video-streaming

Im working on a project with multiple face detection algorithms. I was wandering if i can select which camera i want to open in JAVASCRIPT.

I use Google Chrome - Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

For the moment i just use my laptop web-cam but i want to use a better camera (dslr, goPro, even mobile devices) to detect more and more detail about the face for image processing purposes (e.g. depth-maps).

I know i can use something like this

```
navigator.getUserMedia
```

but this will return devices just of type ImageDevices
[image]

---

### **Is there any way to connect external cameras (either with WI-FI,BT, USB)?**

Comment: https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/android-3.0-honeycomb-is-first-to-implement-the-device-api/ - maybe this is helpful i dont know??

Answer (score 0):

To access multiple cameras from javascript you can refer to the Post [Accessing Multiple camera javascript getusermedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787549/accessing-multiple-camera-javascript-getusermedia) Take care the two cameras must be connected to different USB bus and both must be accessed in the same browser in different or same window.

If you like to use external cameras the best option is to go [onvif](https://www.onvif.org/) with unlimited number of ip cameras connected by wifi or ethernet. To control the cams you can install a node server in your workstation and install the [node-onvif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-onvif) module. There are surveillance cameras with AI face rocognition built-in [Face recognition cameras](https://www.hikvision.com/mtsc/uploads/Ckeditor/Files/2018-04-30/Hikvision_Facial_Recognition_(Oceania)(1)(1).pdf)

To use a smartphone you can follow this video [Smartphone as webcam](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=use%20smartphone%20as%20webcam&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#kpvalbx=1) and use [IP webcam app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) from Playstore

If you prefer to connect a GoPro you have to connect to the AP Access Point of your router or you can configure your laptop as an AP 
then connect your camera via wifi according the following video [GoPro wifi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISzhlMCpk5I) or this other one [GoPro wifi config](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAtW-FISEoo).

You can find some ideas for face recognition like this [Face recognition in Python](https://realpython.com/face-recognition-with-python/) as Open Source solutions based on Linux Python using OpenCV and suitable for [depth maps](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html)

Comment: i work on a local server, so i can't use that unfortunately. I was just wondering if there is a library like kinect.js that i can work with any camera

Comment: Nodejs can be installed in a laptop and has a very small footprint. You can even install it in a Docker container to don't interfere with your system.