# I want to use two webcams on a single web page in html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

I want to capture images from both cameras and use them for some purposes is there anyone who can help me out? any tutorial? library? method? .

Comment: The methods to include webcam images on one's website differ from manufacturer, model, network surrounding, etc. Impossible to answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787549/accessing-multiple-camera-javascript-getusermedia
Here you can find how to solve your problem.

Comment: thnakyou @dev.artisanbiz

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different streams, one for each camera, and show them simultaneously in two `<video>` tags.

The list of available devices is available using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().` After filtering the resulting list for only videoinputs, you have access to the deviceIds without needing permission from the user.

With `getUserMedia` you can then request a stream from the camera with id `camera1Id` using

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: {
    deviceId: { exact: camera1Id }
  }
});
```

The resulting stream can be fed into a `<video>` (referenced here by vid) by calling `vid.srcObject = stream.`

I have done this for two streams from two webcams simultaneously.

Comment: Here you can get details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices