# javascript NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia smartphone back camera

Tags: javascript, camera, asp.net-web-api, smartphone

i need to access to smartphone back-camera through NavigatorUsermedia.getUsermedia(). I found some articles that use only front-camera, without choice.

Some ideas? I know that Camera API are not yet supported from no browser.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625007/enable-rear-camera-with-html5/19055195#19055195) helps you.

Also with the [example](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/).

Answer (score 0):

In the constraints of `getUserMedia()` use this for front camera:

```
{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: "user" } }
```

or this for rear camera:

```
{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add detail to your answer.