# How to change the augmented reality camera in three.js?

Tags: camera, three.js, jsartoolkit

As the example, I try to set up the AR scene in three.js.

I use "jsartoolkit" to do that.

[WebAR](https://artoolkit.github.io/jsartoolkit5/examples/barcode_threejs.html)

I load a JSON model into the AR scene, and it does work.

Now I wonder how could I do to change the camera?

When I open the AR webpage, it always turn on the front device camera of my mobile phone.

I want to use the back device camera to show my WebAR scene.

How should I do?

Comment: I need help......><

Answer (score 1):

Using cameraParam as a property name in your call to getUserMediaThreeScene may be incorrect.

Change:

```
cameraParam: 'Data/camera_para-iPhone 5 rear 640x480 1.0m.dat'
```

To:

```
video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" }}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your reply. I try to modify the code, but it does not work.......

Comment: Check to see if this works in your browser: navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(function(devices) {
    devices.forEach(function(device) {
      if (device.kind==="videoinput") console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label +
        " id = " + device.deviceId);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + error.message);
  });

Comment: Thank you James.
Actually I am a javascript beginner, so I do not knew where should I add those codes.....
Could you should more detail and simple example?

Comment: Perhaps investigate: [enable rear camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625007/enable-rear-camera-with-html5)

Comment: Thank you so much! James! I think the simple example is what I need.

I will try it~!

Comment: @kevin-hsiao any word on this?