# get media device with Java and HTML

Tags: java, html, css, camera

I have a web page template that detects cameras, could someone please help me add a button to take capture from the camera, and that capture shows the image data URL in the text box, I tried to add this but can't integrate that to JS code.
Here is what I tried to insert. Maybe that is the incorrect code... :(

```
> <button id="click-photo">Take Photo</button> <div
> id="dataurl-container">
>     <canvas id="canvas" width="800%" height="600"></canvas>
>     <div id="dataurl-header">Image Data URL</div>
>     <textarea id="dataurl" readonly></textarea> </div>
> 
> JS -->
> 
> click_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
>     canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
>       let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
>     
>     dataurl.value = image_data_url;
>     dataurl_container.style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Camera selection</title>
  <style>
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: #f0293e;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  background: #ffffff;
  min-height: 80vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.controls {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background: #333e5a;
}

.controls {
  color: #fff;
}
.controls p {
  margin: 0;
}
.controls > div {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.controls > div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
  background: #333e5a;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Camera test</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="button">Get camera</button>
      <select id="select">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <video id="video" autoplay playsinline></video>
  </main>



  <script>
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const select = document.getElementById('select');
let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
let dataurl = document.querySelector("#dataurl");
let currentStream;


    
    

function stopMediaTracks(stream) {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    track.stop();
  });
}


function gotDevices(mediaDevices) {
  select.innerHTML = '';
  select.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
  let count = 1;
  mediaDevices.forEach(mediaDevice => {
    if (mediaDevice.kind === 'videoinput') {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = mediaDevice.deviceId;
      const label = mediaDevice.label || `Camera ${count++}`;
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(label);
      option.appendChild(textNode);
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  });
}



button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (typeof currentStream !== 'undefined') {
    stopMediaTracks(currentStream);
  }
  

  const videoConstraints = {};
  if (select.value === '') {
    videoConstraints.facingMode = 'environment';
  } else {
    videoConstraints.deviceId = { exact: select.value };
  }
  const constraints = {
    video: videoConstraints,
    audio: false
  };

  
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
      currentStream = stream;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    })
    .then(gotDevices)
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  
});

  




navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices);


  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need exactly like that https://usefulangle.com/demos/352/camera-capture-photo.html
But in the button Start camera I want to select what camera I need

Comment: Does this help? (Has fairly recent answer giving code for Android at least) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483160/which-camera-will-open-getusermedia-api-in-mobile-device-front-or-rear#:~:text=There%27s%20a%20solution%20where%20the%20user%20can%20select,%28which%20works%20on%20current%20chrome%20%3E%3D%2030%29%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fsimpl.info%2Fgetusermedia%2Fsources%2F

Comment: @AHaworth nope I need that for web, not for Android

Comment: The answers were in terms of the web (HTML5 and JS).